# In T-SQL how to select only the top(not max) value in a group of record

Tags: sql-server

I have some sample data as follows

```
 Name     Value   Timestamp
  a        23      2016/12/23 11:23
  a        43      2016/12/23 12:55
  b         12     2016/12/23 12:55
```

I want to select the latest value for a and b. When I used Last_Value, I used the following query

```
 Select Name, Last_Value(Value) over (partition by Name order by timestamp) from table
```

This returned 2 rows for a, but I wanted it grouped so that I get only the last entered value for each name. So I had to use sub queries.

```
select x.Name,x.Value from (Select Name, Last_Value(Value) over (partition by Name order by timestamp) ) as x group by x.Name,x.Value
```

This again returns 2 records for a...I just wanted to do a group by and orderby and instaed of selelcting the max() wanted to select the top record.

Can anybody tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One method doesn't use window functions:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.timestamp = (select max(t2.timestamp) from table t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```

Otherwise, the subquery method is fine, although I would often use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation rather than `last_value()` (or `first_value()` with a descending `order by`).

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support `first_value()` or `last_value()` as an aggregation function, only as a window function.